# I want to change background colour when I click input

Tags: javascript, html, function, input, onclick

```
 <input type="submit" value="Login" onclick="myFunction">

  <!-- Project -->
  <script>
    
    function myFunction(){
      document.getElementById("input[tpye="submit"]").style.backgroundColor="blue";
    }
    
  </script>
```

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve], including the HTML you're trying to update. You also have a typo: "tpye". And you're trying to use double quotes inside double quotes which will give you an error. You should look at your devtools (F12) console to try and debug your code. You should probably read the documentation for [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) too. It looks like you want [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) instead.

Comment: Sorry @isherwood. I hadn't realised you'd kept Sam's edit in. I mistakenly thought you took it out. I've reverted back to the original question (but with formatting) so that we're not making stuff up and just guessing at answers based on things that we think _should_ be there.

Comment: No one is adding things. The OP had an input in there. See the [source](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/6d67f4b6-82f1-44c4-987f-229f73d419bb/view-source) of the original post.

Comment: I admit defeat. But that's not great UX if I have to look at the source of the question rather than look at the question. IMO, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

`getElementById` gets the element with that id. You're probably looking for `querySelector` instead, which will select the element that matches that selector:

```js
function myFunction(){ 
    document.querySelector("input[type='submit']").style.backgroundColor="blue";
 }
```

Comment: I know that you (Spectric) know this but for the OP: You shouldn't use `.style` in modern web development. You should use `.classList` instead to apply style changes through classes rather then adding inline-style for varios reasons such as specificty weight issues.

Answer (score 1):

You have done three mistakes in your code snippet

1. You have not given () to the function call
2. You have written incorrect spelling in the querySelector of "type" word
3. You are calling the getElementById() function but you have not given id to the input box

```html
<input type="submit" value="Login" onclick="myFunction()">

<!-- Project -->
<script>
  
  function myFunction(){
    document.querySelector("input[type='submit']").style.backgroundColor="blue";
  }
  
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the javascript function you are using 'getElementById' which means that it'll look for the DOM elements with the id you have provided, and the problem is you didn't provided any id.

You have to first give an id to the button

```
<button id="some_id">Click</button>
```

And then align your function in this way.

```
function myFunction(){ document.getElementById("some_id").style.backgroundColor="blue"; }
```

Answer (score -1):

this is my solution to your problem. In your case you have some type of input, you need first to add an event listener to the input, which will execute some function on a specific event. In our case, we will execute the change color function.

This is a quick solution to your problem.

```js
let button = document.getElementById('changecolor');

let input = document.getElementById('basic-input');


function changeBackground(){
    // Change the background of the page
    document.body.style.background = 'red';
  
  // Change background of the button
  button.style.background = 'blue';
}

button.addEventListener('click' , changeBackground);

input.addEventListener('click' , changeBackground);
```

```html
<button id="changecolor">Change background</button>

<input type="text" placeholder="basic input" id="basic-input">
```